# Can't compile Xcode 4 "modernized" project on Xcode 3.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4, interface-builder

I have recently updated my Xcode 3.2.4 to Xcode 4.1. v4.1 got installed on `/Developer` folder sending my XCode 3.2.4 to `/Developer-Old` folder.

After v4.1 installation, I "modernized" my project on v4.1, but decided to stick with XCode 3.2.4 for now. When I try to compile my "modernized" project on XCode 3.2.4 I keep receiving the following error on all my XIB files:

`This version of Interface Builder does not support documents of type "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Document (XIB 3.x)" targeting "iPhone/iPod touch".`

Any ideas? Is it possible to reverse the changes that "Modernize" action did to my project? Or how can I compile the project on Xcode 3.2.4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling both versions of XCode (3.2.4 & 4.1) and installing XCode 3.2.6 on Lion(was only available for download on DevCenter from v3.x). This [link](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion) helped me much.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of software do not support new versioned Documents. So the way Xcode and Interface Builder handled their files are going to be different.